# EditText in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I want to display edit text in my grid view item. The problem is that in this case GridView doesn't handle ItemClick event (as it is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183609/onitemclicklistener-not-triggered-on-android-gridview))

My GridView item looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/main_resume_item_layout"
            android:layout_height="160dip"
            android:layout_width="150dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_height="120dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="30dip"
    android:background="#FF5"
    android:paddingRight="10dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/created"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Created"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resume_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="18.01.2013"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/resume_progress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dip"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:max="70"
        android:progress="50"
        android:background="@drawable/progress"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resume_title"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example resume"
    android:textColor="#5544FF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/resume_title_edit"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example resume"
    android:textColor="#5544FF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

I wonder is there any way to have EditText in GridView and handle ItemClick event? Maybe someone know some workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

add this to all other view except edittext in you layout.

OR,
You can add click event in your adapter class.

Comment: I've added this, but it doesn't help. OnItemClickListener for GridView  still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, I think i solved this problem by adding click event to layout in my adapter