# Neither setOnItemSelectedListener nor setOnClickListener works for GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapterview

The GridView is the following:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"/>
```

The Java code is the following:

```
gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setNumColumns(iColumnCount);
gridview.setAdapter(dta);
gridview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int iPosition, long l) {
        utility.logd("gridview", "selected item position:" + iPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        utility.logd("gridview", "nothing selected.");
    }
});
gridview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        utility.logd("gridview", "item clicked");
    }
});
```

Only onNothingSelected() is called once after the apps starts. None of the other listeners is called when the focus on the GridView is changed with a remote control, or any item is clicked.

Could anyone offer a tip on how to make the listeners work?
Everything else of the GirdView works as expected.

**Edit:** The following is the layout for each grid cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/biyee_relativeLayoutRoot">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="snapshot"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="onClick_imageButton"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCaption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewModel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Model"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPosition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="n"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Edit (2):**
Per [the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183609/onitemclicklistener-not-triggered-on-android-gridview) of Daniel Nugent, I removed the ImageButton from the custom item view layout for the purpose of testing, and OnItemSelectedListener started working perfectly.  Therefore the culprit is ImageButton.  It seems any clickable object would ruin OnItemSelectedListener.

**Edit (3):**  For the sake of testing, I used the following layout for the custom item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/red">

</LinearLayout>
```

OnItemSelectedListener works perfectly, but OnClickListener and OnItemClickListener are never called no matter whether I use a mouse or remote control to click an item.

Comment: I guess you need `onItemClickListener()` instead of `onItemSelectedListener()`

Comment: Unfortunately, GridView does not have setOnItemClickedListener. There is no AdapterView.onItemSelectedListener.

Comment: GridView does not have onItemClickListener()? Does API be fooled? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: are you using any third party gridview?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  There was something wrong with Android Studio IntelliSense.  I may be relying too much on it.   You are right that GridView has setOnClickListener.  Unfortunately, it does not work either for either a table with touchscreen or Android TV with a remote control.

Comment: It´s just an assumption, but your problem could be here: `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` on your xml. Try to remove, clean project and build again.

Comment: I have tried all kinds combination with android:descendantFocusability, android:descendantFocusability,  android:focusableInTouchMode to no avail.  I have just tried what you suggested.  It did not make any difference.

Comment: You might need to set focusable to false for Views in the xml that gets inflated for each GridView item, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183609/onitemclicklistener-not-triggered-on-android-gridview

Comment: @DanielNugent Thank you for the tip. In light of your comment, I edited the post by adding the layout for the grid cell.  Perhaps ImageButton is the culprit.

Comment: @DanielNugent  Per the tip of your provided post, I found the culprit is the ImageButton in the custom item view layout.  Please see Edit(2).  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should be able to use the ImageButton by using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27056992/4409409

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work.  I am trying ImageView now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OnItemClickListener` instead of `onItemSelectedListener`

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                //Your Logic here
        }
);
```

`onItemSelectedListener` will do the job if you implements some kind of selection like arrows or some other thing.

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been
>   selected. This callback is invoked only when the newly selected
>   position is different from the previously selected position or if
>   there was no selected item.
>
> Impelmenters can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to
>   access the data associated with the selected item.

Comment: Thank you for lending a hand. GridView does not have setOnItemClickedListener.  There is no AdapterView.onItemSelectedListener.  I want the listener to be called when the focus is moved from one item to another.

Comment: @Hong than are you sure you are actually selecting another item?

Comment: @Hong GridView does have OnItemClickListener checkout this example: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I was wrong.  There was something wrong with Android Studio IntelliSense.  I may be relying too much on it.   You are right that GridView has setOnClickListener.  Unfortunately, it does not work  for either a table with touchscreen or Android TV with a remote control.

Comment: @Hong join me here in the chat room to avoid posting too many comments here [Room for Sid and Hong](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129574/room-for-sid-and-hong)